# Why does my CPU fan stop spinning after Windows Vista starts?

Tags: windows-vista, shutdown, fan

It is such a strange behaviour on my Acer Aspire 5720 system running Windows Vista Italian version.

I have been using my laptop for a year and recently it often shuts down immediately without displaying any message. I discovered that the CPU is too hot, the CPU fan is not spinning when Windows starts, but the interesting thing is that when I just turn on the computer with the Power button, the fan spins well, only after 2 seconds, when Windows Vista is launched, it's time for the CPU fan to stop.

I wonder what happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be a hardware problem.

Enter BIOS setup, wait a minute or two, and see whether the fan keeps spinning.
If it doesn't, you probably have a hardware problem.
You can also try booting to a CD (eg, Knoppix) and see whether it stops spinning.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it's a hardware problem, sometimes it works, sometimes it does not :-s

Comment: I'm not sure if it's actually a "problem" -- perhaps there's some ACPI thing that's done by Windows, like changing passive/active cooling modes?

Answer (score 3):

Slaks suggestion is not one that's thrown out into the air. This is a valuable troubleshooting step that will help you to determine whether or not your issue is hardware or software related.

The fan should continue to work while in the BIOS. If it does not, then you know the issue is hardware related. Most likely the motherboard, or thermal paste may need to be replaced.

FYI: Missing or deteriorated thermal paste will cause the CPU to overheat! or in your case motherboard will shut off power to avoid overheating the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

My Dell laptop has the same problem. I have discovered the following reason for fan not working. When a CD is already present in the drive , and switch on my laptop, usually the fan wont work. As soon as i remove the CD our of the drive, fan starts functioning.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me on my Acer Aspire running Windows 10: (I had the same issue as yours, and the fan stopped soonly after entering bios): If you totally shutdown your system, and the two or one led lights stay on (the power/wall plug light) then unplug your machine and flip it over! You will find a small pinhole that you will need to stick a pin into (It looks like a little AA battery partially coming out of it's holder). When you stick the pin into it, you must feel a click. If you don't, get a longer/thinner pin or reallign it. Hold it until one/both the lights turn off and then problem solved! You may now boot plugged in or not and your system will worke fine dandy and well!